# Alma Linux - Gateway fall back is not working, when gateway IP with lower metrics is down

Tags: gateway, static-routes

Currently I am using Alma-Linux, where I need to create 2 default gateways for the **same** NIC. Main intent of 2 default gateway configuration is.. when any one of the gateways is down then it will fall back to other working gateway

Gateway Configuration
Below IPs are used for routing

1. 11.12.13.2 (default gateway - with lower metric value 30)
2. 11.12.13.1 (default gateway configured via static route - with higher metric value  40)

Both IPs are ping-able.

For testing fail over scenario, I disabled the gateway ip with lower metrics IP(11.12.13.2) and performed the traceroute command on a random remote host which is in different subnet.

command : traceroute 17.18.19.2

but traceroute result is destination unreachable.

In this scenario, I assume packets will go through default gateway route 11.12.13.1 ip as a fall back option. since configured gateway is down. It is not working as I expected.

Note: In windows, gateway fall back is happening irrespective of metric values.

Comment: Why ask a new question when there was https://serverfault.com/questions/1141388/alma-linux-static-route-configuration-is-not-working-as-fall-back-mechanism-wh ?

Comment: As I wrote in your other question, there's at least a mistake on the additional "default" route. But in this question you write no output from the result of a command, so any mistake like that one is now invisible. Fixing this mistake won't make it work though.

Comment: @A.B Yeah my last question you are talking 
about is resolved by using 0.0.0.0/0 as destination IP. This question is specifically asked in the context of metric value of gateways.

Comment: I can't tell the difference between the two questions by reading them. Moreover you didn't answer to nor delete the other question while you tell it's solved.

Comment: @A.B Imagine two default gateways are assigned with metric values  10 and 20 respectively. When default gateway with lower value 10 is down then expectation is other gateway with value 20 is should come take over automatically without user interaction

Comment: That's what you want, not what can be done (by a few clicks). Anyway fix the former question first. Btw, I have no answer to provide, but someone might.

Comment: But automatic fail over switch not happening in case of 2 different metric values. If 2 gateways have SAME value then it's working. Is it the expected behavior in linux

Comment: Where did you read this? Are they on the same interface or on different interfaces (not your case with a single interface)?

Comment: I tried practically in my linux system with different combinations and came to this conclusion. When two gateways are up and running then communication  is happening through the gateway with lower metric value. If I bring that gatewAy down other gateway with value 20 should take care of communication automatically. That's not happening it's my observation. I tried on same interface it's my use case. I tested the same in windows it's working fine

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Alma Linux -Static route configuration is not working as fall back mechanism, when default gateway is down](https://serverfault.com/questions/1141388/alma-linux-static-route-configuration-is-not-working-as-fall-back-mechanism-wh)

Comment: @GregAskew: Not answered yet. This question is variation of my previous question though both are related to  gateway failover scenario but here question is related to it's expected behavior in case of 2 gateways configured with 2 different metrics on the same single interface

Comment: In Linux, only the default route with the lowest metric will be considered, and if that fails, it will not automatically fall back to the next highest metric. However, you can achieve your desired behavior by using some more advanced routing tools and methods, such as iproute2 and routing tables.

Comment: Install iproute2.   Configure the primary default route:
sudo ip route add default via 11.12.13.2 dev eth0 metric 30
Configure the secondary default route:
sudo ip route add default via 11.12.13.1 dev eth0 metric 40
Add routing tables:
Edit /etc/iproute2/rt_tables:
Add the following at the end:
10 rt1
20 rt2
Set up rules and routes:
sudo ip rule add from all lookup rt1 prio 100
sudo ip rule add from all lookup rt2 prio 200
sudo ip route add default via 11.12.13.2 dev eth0 table rt1
sudo ip route add default via 11.12.13.1 dev eth0 table rt2

Answer (score 1):

There is **no** fully automatic ready-made fall back in Linux and it was never there. You have wrong expectation of what Linux could do for you.

Routing code doesn't track the availability of the gateway. In case several similar routes with different metrics are present, numerically lower metric is always selected, with **no additional logic** that can consider the state of that gateway. It's because nothing checks whether gateway is still alive, the system doesn't care about the gateway. Even if the gateway specified in the route is down, nothing in the system will know about this, route will still exist and the system will use it.

You **need some external mechanism** which will ping or otherwise check gateways and torn down their routes if not available. Only then, without the route to the failed gateway, next best route will be considered.

Comment: How about the behaviour when we use 2 default gateways on 2 DIFFERENT interfaces in a same system?

Comment: Nowhere in my answer I am saying anything about interfaces. Routing *includes* the stage of selection of outgoing interface, which implies when it is started there is no any knowledge of interfaces. So this simply doesn't matter.

Comment: I forgot interesting "corner" case. If the *interface* where gateway is defined goes down (loses carrier) all routes associated with it also disappear. In that case next best route will be considered. A smart router itself can put down its interface to signify to clients it has no internet access, to exploit this behaviour, but any switch between the router and a client device will break such setup. Personally I think the availability of the gateway or status of its interface is not sufficient for robust route selection; you have to check if there is actually internet behind the gateway.